# How to make Raspberry Pi an Internet whitelist

Tags: pi-zero, internet, dns

I want to set-up an Internet whitelist (a feature NOT AVAILABLE in my modem/router) using a Raspberry Pi Zero W (RPi0W). As answered in [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/16957/whitelist-internet-filter), I have made changes to **/etc/privoxy/config**:

[image: Screenshot of /etc/privoxy/config]

As in this example, the RPi0W is supposed to allow only *facebook.com* and *amazon.com*. But it is not happening. I can browse any website.

I also have tried setting the DNS in WiFi settings of the client machine (like the computer I am writing this post on) to IP address of the Pi.

[image: IP Configuration of WiFi]

**192.168.43.128** is the IP of the Pi.

Please note that I have installed **PiHole** on the Pi which is working as expected with IP configuration as above. I have tried adding the whitelist domains/websites to Whitelist of PiHole (just for a try), it again allows all traffic through it (except ads). I can Blacklist desired domains in PiHole though.

Any ideas what is wrong with my configuration of the RPi0W?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if that matters, but [there](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/16964/78211) are spaces before and after the curly brackets. Have you tried "{ +block }" instead of "{+block}"?

Comment: @Fabian I tried what you suggested. Still no luck. I have updated the image. Thanks any ways.

Comment: How do you start the script `privoxy`?

Comment: I don't know if 'privoxy' has to be executed. I just followed what was mentioned in the referenced post.

Comment: I can not test it atm but [Privoxy 3.0.26 User Manual, 4. Quickstart to Using Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/quickstart.html) says "Start Privoxy, if the installation program has not done this already (may vary according to platform). See the section [Starting Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/startup.html)." To check if `privoxy` is already running you could run `ps axu | grep -i privoxy`. What result do you get?

Comment: Remove the other DNS server from your router (8.8.4.4) so there is only the Pihole. Build your entire whitelist, including Raspberry Pi repositories, then blacklist all sites.

Comment: @AndyAnderson I removed the DNS 8.8.4.4. It blocked all websites, excluding google.com. But the sites in `WHITELIST` are also being blocked blocked. May be the second DNS is being used by PiHole to access the Internet.

Comment: No. The secondary DNS on the router is used if the Primary fails. The Pihole has forwarding DNS servers set (check in the web settings for the DNS tab) for after it has done its filtering.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. That's why all sites were blocked when I deleted second DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Setup dnsmasq to use 127.0.0.1* as its default dns server, which will result in every dns request failing. Then set up your whitelisted domains in dnsmasq.conf, as eg
`server=/facebook.com/8.8.8.8`
`server=/twitter.com/8.8.8.8`
`server=/reddit.com/8.8.8.8`
`server=/pornhub.com/8.8.8.8`
`etc, etc`
which will then make queries to those domains use google dns.

* any local IP you know will not be running a dns server

[Taken from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/6zfock/block_everything_that_is_not_on_whitelist_how/dn7g98r?utm_source=reddit-android)

Comment: Thanks. I am working on **dnsmasq** as you suggested. Done quite a lot of things so far. I can update dnsmasq.conf and add `server=/xxxxxx` lines. But please tell me how do I "Setup dnsmasq to use 127.0.0.1* as its default dns server"?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/799200 asks the question on how to bind dnsmasq to loopback but you may need to read the dnsmasq manual or pro actively search that one.